# iloc in a loop to replace wrong values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am trying to go over my dataset and to change the value of rating_denominator based on some condition. But this method is giving me a 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds' error message.

If any of you have any clue, it'll be awesome.

Thanks

```
for i, row in twitter_copy[twitter_copy.rating_denominator != 10].iterrows():
    d = row.rating_denominator
    k = row.rating_numerator
    if d == 0:
       # twitter_copy.rating_denominator.replace(d,10, inplace=True)
        twitter_copy.iloc[i]['rating_denominator'] = 10
    elif d < 10 and k > 10:
        #twitter_copy.rating_denominator.replace(d,10, inplace=True)
        twitter_copy.iloc[i]['rating_denominator'] = 10
    else:
       twitter_copy.iloc[i]['rating_denominator'] = 10
```

Comment: [Never modify something you are iterating over](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows).

Comment: Why iterate the DataFrame?  Generally speaking, if you need to iterate there’s a better solution.  Have a look at `numpy.where()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the df.loc instead of iloc might help you?

```
for i in df[df['columnA'!=10]]:
    df.loc[df['columnA'] <10 & df['columnB']>10, 'columnA'] = 10
    df.loc[df['columnA'] == 0, 'columnA'] = 10
```

It might do the trick, let me know!